# Is there a way for Tokens to be refreshed for Wordpress OAuth2.0?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, wordpress-rest-api, refresh-token

I am working on Wordpress.com API..
this is my refrence: 
https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/

I already have the token and stored it in the database. I was looking on how i can refresh this whenever its about time to expire without user intervention.
I have experience with OAuth2.0 with other apps so i have some idea how to do it. It seems this one is a different case, if you can check my reference there are no indications on how i can refresh a token.

I tried experimenting  while referring to this: 
https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/
to solve the problem and done this:

```
POST https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token
params:
grant_type=refresh_token
token=<MY_SAVED_TOKEN>
client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>
client_secret=<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>
redirect_uri=example.com
```

but grant_type refresh_token was not accepted(or was not even existing)
if i change grant_type to authorization_code - it will not accept my token

Can you please teach me how you refresh yours with Wordpress API Oauth2?